# How to get minutes in between two different dates?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi i am using Javascript and i want to get each and every minute between two dates for example:

```
firstDate: 2019-04-02 02:03:00
secondDate: 2019-04-03 03:04:00
```

So my final output result should return like this:

```
2019-04-02 02:03:00
2019-04-02 02:04:00
2019-04-02 02:05:00
.
.
.
2019-04-03 03:04:00
```

Here is the code which i tried

```js
var boxingDay = new Date("2019-04-02 02:03:00");
var nextWeek  = new Date("2019-04-03 03:04:00");

function getDatesRange(startDate, stopDate){
    const ONE_DAY = 60*1000;
    var days= [];
    var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        days.push(new Date (currentDate));
        currentDate = currentDate - 1 + 1 + ONE_DAY;
    }
    return days.join("\n");
}

console.log(getDatesRange(boxingDay,nextWeek))

/* var map = getDates(boxingDay, nextWeek).map((times) => {
console.log(Date.parse(times))
}) */

/* console.log((getDates( boxingDay, nextWeek ))); */
```

The problem is I am getting correct output but I need in the form of an array, like below and reuse the function if I am reusing, it returns me an empty array.

```
[[2019-04-02 02:03:00],[2019-04-02 02:04:00].....]
```

Any solution TIA.

Comment: ignore comment, was confused that the title of the question is nothing to do with the question

Comment: Just so that I am clear, you want the above answer in an array, correct?

Comment: I want it in array and also function reuse here in my code if i am using it returns me an empty array

Answer (score 1):

Using your code as a basis, you can do this as follows (note that I'm using `.toISOString()`, you can change this according to your needs):

```js
const boxingDay = new Date("2019-04-02 02:03:00");
const nextWeek  = new Date("2019-04-03 03:04:00");

function getDatesRange(startDate, stopDate){
    const ONE_MINUTE = 60*1000;
    const days= [];
    let currentDate = new Date(startDate);
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        days.push([currentDate.toISOString()]);
        currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + ONE_MINUTE);
    }
    return days;
}

console.log(getDatesRange(boxingDay,nextWeek));
```

Comment: Thanks eol for the answer but when i try to reuse in other files it returns me an empty array.

Comment: How do you call the function in the other files?

Comment: I meant "can you add the code where you call the function?" :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, that you could use `while` loop with format function, each iteration increate the minute

```js
const firstDate = new Date('2019-04-02 02:03:00')
const secondDate = new Date('2019-04-03 03:04:00')

const formatDate = dateObj => {
  const year = String(dateObj.getFullYear()).padStart(4, '0')
  const month = String(dateObj.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')
  const date = String(dateObj.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')
  const hour = String(dateObj.getHours()).padStart(2, '0')
  const minute = String(dateObj.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0')
  const second = String(dateObj.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0')

  return `${year}-${month}-${date} ${hour}:${minute}:${second}`
}

const res = []

const iteratedDate = new Date(firstDate.getTime())
while (iteratedDate <= secondDate) {
  res.push(formatDate(iteratedDate))
  iteratedDate.setMinutes(iteratedDate.getMinutes() + 1)
}

// res array is large so I sliced the first 10 amd the last 10
console.log(res.slice(0, 10))
console.log(res.slice(res.length - 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach using a `for` loop; it also avoids creating a new `Date` instance for each minute iterated.

```js
const p = new Date("2019-04-02T23:57:00");
const q = new Date("2019-04-03T00:03:00");
const r = [];
for(const d = new Date(p); d <= q; d.setTime(d.getTime() + 60000))
{
    r.push(d.toISOString().substring(0, 19).replace(/T/, " "));
}
const s = r.join("\n");
console.log(s);
```